# Can I add any image other than a banner logo to the Click & Pledge donation page?

Tags: page-layout

I'm attempting to set up a custom donation page but I want it to match the format of our current donation page. Ideally there would be a logo banner (which I do know how to create in C&P) and another image on the left half of the donation page itself. Is this possible? If it is, how do I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in numerous ways. You don't need to use visualforce elements. Instead you can use essentially the same html code as you have in your other page. Since I've not seen your original donation page, I can't tell you how to write the specific code for it. I'm not certain what you mean by C&P, but if you can open the resulting page in a text editor and it's html, you could copy and paste it into a visualforce page.

It sounds as though you need to go through some of the visualforce tutorials to learn more. I recommend the following resources [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm) and the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm).